# Print something in Makefile only if it was actually done

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to make my Makefile output text instead of the commands it is executing, and I found preceding commands with "@" will mute them, and I can use `echo` to display whatever I want.
However, when my project is fully built and I run `make`, it will output `make[1]: Nothing to be done for` all'.` ***as well as*** my text, and I was wondering if there was a way for me to only run echo commands (or whatever) when the Makefile actually does something.
This is my current Makefile, so you can see what I have so far:

```
NAME = push_swap

SRCS = push_swap.c push.c swap.c rotate.c reverse.c \
        pick_sort.c push_swap_min_max.c small_stack.c big_stack.c \
        repeat_functions.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

LIBFT = libft

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra
MAKEFLAGS = --no-print-directory

RM = rm -f

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(LIBFT) $(OBJS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) ./libft/libft.a -o $(NAME)
    @echo "linked successfully"

$(OBJS):
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRCS)
    @echo "compiled successfully"

$(LIBFT):
    @if [ ! -d "libft" ]; then git clone https://github.com/Nixo371/libft-42; echo "cloned libft repository"; fi
    @$(MAKE) -C libft all
    @echo "libft compiled correctly"


clean:
    @$(RM) $(OBJS)
    @$(MAKE) -C libft clean
    @echo "removed object files from push_swap"

fclean: clean
    @$(RM) $(NAME)
    @$(MAKE) -C libft fclean
    @echo "removed $(NAME)"

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all libft clean fclean re
```

I have tried looking in the documentation to see if I could find tags/options for `make` that would mute the command, or use its exit code (I'm assuming the 1 in `make[1]: Nothing to be done for` all'.` is the exit code) to provide different results. But I couldn't find anything of the sort

Comment: "Nothing to be done ... as well as my text" - it shouldn't do that. Check again that things are and behave as you describe here.

Comment: Not sure what to say, running make compiles the program and displays the proper `echo` commands. Running make again after this shows `make[1]: Nothing to be done for all'.` as well as: "libft compiled correctly" and "linked successfully"

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Target "libft" is phony since the recipe doesn't create a file by that name. More likely creating file libft/bin/libft.a, or something similar. Because the file "libft" doesn't exist the recipes are always run. Try read some on the topic of "recursive make" to get an idea of how to handle it.

Comment: Thank you!!! I changed the .PHONY and the LIBFT variable to something else and now it works

Answer (score 1):

The `make[1]` note is a message coming from a recursive invocation of make -- the `1` meaning it is one level deep in the recursion.

In this case it is likely coming from the action you have for LIBFT:

```
@$(MAKE) -C libft all
```

which will run make using the Makefile in the `libft` directory for the target `all` (and which apparently has nothing to do for that target)

You can shut that up completely by redirecting its stdout/stderr to /dev/null:

```
@$(MAKE) -C libft all >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or you may be able to change that subdirectory Makefile to be silent when there is nothing to do.

Comment: "Or you may be able to change that subdirectory Makefile to be silent when there is nothing to do" How would I go about doing that?